# modify an existing function from .bashrc or .zshrc

Tags: bash, zsh

There is a function defined in `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_git`

```
(( $+functions[_git-diff] )) ||
_git-diff () {
  local curcontext=$curcontext state line ret=1
  declare -A opt_args

  local -a diff_options diff_stage_options
  __git_setup_diff_options
  __git_setup_diff_stage_options

  _arguments -C -s $endopt \
    $* \
    $diff_options \
    '(--exit-code)--quiet[disable all output]' \
    $diff_stage_options \
    '(--cached --staged)--no-index[show diff between two paths on the filesystem]' \
    '(--cached --staged --no-index)'{--cached,--staged}'[show diff between index and named commit]' \
    '(-)--[start file arguments]' \
    '*:: :->from-to-file' && ret=0

  case $state in
    (from-to-file)
      # If "--" is part of $opt_args, this means it was specified before any
      # $words arguments. This means that no heads are specified in front, so
      # we need to complete *changed* files only.
      if [[ -n ${opt_args[(I)--]} ]]; then
        if [[ -n ${opt_args[(I)--cached|--staged]} ]]; then
          __git_changed-in-index_files && ret=0
        else
          __git_changed-in-working-tree_files && ret=0
        fi
        return ret
      fi

      # If "--no-index" was given, only file paths need to be completed.
      if [[ -n ${opt_args[(I)--no-index]} ]]; then
        _alternative 'files::_files' && ret=0
        return ret
      fi

      # Otherwise, more complex conditions need to be checked.
      case $CURRENT in
        (1)
          local files_alt='files::__git_changed-in-working-tree_files'
          if [[ -n ${opt_args[(I)--cached|--staged]} ]]; then
            files_alt='files::__git_changed-in-index_files'
          fi

          _alternative \
            'commit-ranges::__git_commit_ranges' \
            'blobs-and-trees-in-treeish::__git_blobs_and_trees_in_treeish' \
            $files_alt \
            'blobs::__git_blobs ' && ret=0
          ;;
        (2)
          # Check if first argument is something special. In case of committish ranges and committishs offer a full list compatible completions.
          if __git_is_committish_range $line[1]; then
            # Example: git diff branch1..branch2 <tab>
            __git_tree_files ${PREFIX:-.} $(__git_committish_range_last $line[1]) && ret=0
          elif __git_is_committish $line[1] || __git_is_treeish $line[1]; then
            # Example: git diff branch1 <tab>
            _alternative \
              'commits::__git_commits' \
              'blobs-and-trees-in-treeish::__git_blobs_and_trees_in_treeish' \
              'files::__git_tree_files ${PREFIX:-.} HEAD' && ret=0
          elif __git_is_blob $line[1]; then
            _alternative \
              'files::__git_cached_files' \
              'blobs::__git_blobs' && ret=0
          elif [[ -n ${opt_args[(I)--cached|--staged]} ]]; then
            # Example: git diff --cached file1 <tab>
            __git_changed-in-index_files && ret=0
          else
            # Example: git diff file1 <tab>
            __git_changed-in-working-tree_files && ret=0
          fi
          ;;
        (*)
          if __git_is_committish_range $line[1]; then
            # Example: git diff branch1..branch2 file1 <tab>
            __git_tree_files ${PREFIX:-.} $(__git_committish_range_last $line[1]) && ret=0
          elif { __git_is_committish $line[1] && __git_is_committish $line[2] } ||
              __git_is_treeish $line[2]; then
            # Example: git diff branch1 branch2 <tab>
            __git_tree_files ${PREFIX:-.} $line[2] && ret=0
          elif __git_is_committish $line[1] || __git_is_treeish $line[1]; then
            # Example: git diff branch file1 <tab>
            # Example: git diff branch -- f<tab>
            __git_tree_files ${PREFIX:-.} HEAD && ret=0
          elif __git_is_blob $line[1] && __git_is_blob $line[2]; then
            _nothing
          elif [[ -n ${opt_args[(I)--cached|--staged]} ]]; then
            # Example: git diff --cached file1 file2 <tab>
            __git_changed-in-index_files && ret=0
          else
            # Example: git diff file1 file2 <tab>
            __git_changed-in-working-tree_files && ret=0
          fi
          ;;
      esac
      ;;
  esac

  return ret
}
```

I just need to append

```
'files::__git_changed_files ${PREFIX:-.} HEAD' \
```

Above

```
'files::__git_tree_files ${PREFIX:-.} HEAD' && ret=0
```

Currently I have copy-pasted the new function in my `.zshrc`, and it is working.

However, I think there is a cleaner way to override existing function using `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` like the following:

```
_git-diff 2>/dev/null 
functions[_git-diff-orig]=$functions[_git-diff]  
_git-diff() {
    _git-diff-orig "$@"
    ... 
}
```

But I am not sure how to do it. Can anyone please help. Just to be clear, I want to override the function using `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` so that it can be more portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `zsh`, the value in the `functions` associative array is the normalized code text.  This means you can use any of the usual text manipulation methods to modify it:

```bash
foo() {
  echo before
  echo and after
}

foo
# => before
# => and after

functions[foo]=${functions[foo]/echo before/echo before;echo during}

foo
# => before
# => during
# => and after

functions foo
# => foo () {
# =>   echo before
# =>   echo during
# =>   echo and after
# => }
```

Interestingly, zsh will parse, validate, and normalize the code on assignment to the `functions` array - it's essentially the same process as declaring a function normally.  That's why the output from `functions foo` has a newline, even though the string substitution used a semicolon.

Adding these lines to `~/.zshrc` should work for your example:

```bash
current="'files::__git_tree_files \${PREFIX:-.} HEAD'"
replacement="'files::__git_changed_files \${PREFIX:-.} HEAD' $current"
functions[_git-diff]=${functions[_git-diff]/$current/$replacement}
```

### Additional ways to modify a function

There are a number of ways to alter text in shell languages, and some of these
may work better for more complex changes to functions.  Note that more changes
can make the process more fragile, since updates to the base code could trip
up the patching process.

Also note that the changes are applied to the code that is stored in the
`functions` array; that may not match what is in the original source file.

#### Using `patch`

An obvious choice, since we're patching code.  The `patch` utility modifies
text based on the output from `diff` (usually `diff -u`).  The utility can handle
some whitespace differences, and some errors such as incorrect line numbers:

```bash
plan() {
    forecast=${1}
    if [[ $forecast == sun ]]; then
        print "take sunscreen"
        print "wear hat"
    elif [[ $forecast == rain ]]; then
        print "take umbrella"
        print "carry raincoat"
    else
        print "stay home"
    fi
}
plan sun
#=> take sunscreen
#=> wear hat

plan hail
#=> stay home


patchDiff='
--- plan1
+++ plan2
@@ -4,3 +4,5 @@
        print "take sunscreen"
+       print "apply sunscreen"
        print "wear hat"
+       print "use sunglasses"
    elif [[ $forecast == rain ]]
@@ -11,2 +13,3 @@
        print "stay home"
+       print "and relax"
    fi'
functions[plan]=$(print -- $patchDiff \
    | patch -ls -o >(cat) =(print -- $functions[plan]))

plan sun
#=> take sunscreen
#=> apply sunscreen
#=> wear hat
#=> use sunglasses

plan hail
#=> stay home
#=> and relax
```

#### Using `sed`

Using the `sed` stream editor, and building on the previous example:

```bash
sedscript='s/print *\(.*\)/print ${(C):-\1}/'
functions[plan]=$(print $functions[plan] | sed -e $sedscript)

functions plan
#=> plan () {
#=>     forecast=${1} 
#=>     if [[ $forecast == sun ]]
#=>     then
#=>         print ${(C):-"take sunscreen"}
#=>         print ${(C):-"apply sunscreen"}
#=>         print ${(C):-"wear hat"}
#=>         print ${(C):-"use sunglasses"}
#=>     elif [[ $forecast == rain ]]
#=>     then
#=>         print ${(C):-"take umbrella"}
#=>         print ${(C):-"carry raincoat"}
#=>     else
#=>         print ${(C):-"stay home"}
#=>         print ${(C):-"and relax"}
#=>     fi
#=> }

plan rain
#=> Take Umbrella
#=> Carry Raincoat
```

#### By line

This doesn't require matching anything specific in the function.  That's both
good and bad - it's easy to implement, but it can break with even simple
changes to the base function:

```bash
# split the code into an array of lines (f)
lines=("${(f)functions[plan]}")

# add code in the middle
newCode=(
    ${lines[1]}
    'if [[ $forecast == tornado ]]; then
        print "find shelter"
        print "go quickly"
        return
    fi'
    ${lines[2,-1]})

# rejoin array with newlines (F)
functions[plan]=${(F)newCode}

functions plan
#=> plan () {
#=>     forecast=${1} 
#=>     if [[ $forecast == tornado ]]
#=>     then
#=>         print "find shelter"
#=>         print "go quickly"
#=>         return
#=>     fi
#=>     if [[ $forecast == sun ]]
#=>     then
#=>         print ${(C):-"take sunscreen"}
#=>         print ${(C):-"apply sunscreen"}
#=>         print ${(C):-"wear hat"}
#=>         print ${(C):-"use sunglasses"}
#=>     elif [[ $forecast == rain ]]
#=>     then
#=>         print ${(C):-"take umbrella"}
#=>         print ${(C):-"carry raincoat"}
#=>     else
#=>         print ${(C):-"stay home"}
#=>         print ${(C):-"and relax"}
#=>     fi
#=> }

plan tornado
#=> find shelter
#=> go quickly
```

#### Using `functions -c`

If the updated function can be based on a call to the initial function, then `functions -c` (in zsh 5.8 and later) can be used to create a copy to use in the new function:

```bash
functions -c plan plan_orig
plan() {
    print "Here's the list for $1:"
    plan_orig "$@"
}

plan rain
#=> Here's the list for rain:
#=> Take Umbrella
#=> Carry Raincoat
```

There is more information about modifying functions in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/450133).

Comment: Just for the sake of convenience can you please add an example where `foo` has ~10 line of text. And say I want to edit line 5 and 6. I am asking because, I am not sure how to `echo` multiple lines in `functions[foo]=${functions[foo]/echo before/echo before;echo during}`